# Expression in Powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: powerbuilder

I m pretty new to PowerBuilder (12.5 Classic) and trying to find out if what I am doing is  the right way.

I  have three text controls in a PowerBuilder DataWindow named `t1`, `t2`, `t3`.

I am trying with the expressions  so  `t1.Text` property is set to static  `"Hello"`.

`t2.text` property  using the expressions. So in the expression field I specify `describe('t1.Text')`.
When I run it, it correctly displays the `t2.Text` as `"Hello"` (excluding quotes).

Now for `t3` I give the expression as `describe('t2.Text')` which i guess is not the right thing to do because i get the result as:  `describe(~"t2.Text~")`    [inclusive of all the quotes].

I am just trying to get the Evaluated Text  of a text box (here `t2`) and not its expression. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result of a field property expression for a given row in the `dw_1` datawindow by using the `evaluate()` datawindow expression in a `Describe()`:

```
string ls_expression = "t2.text"
string ls_text
ls_text = dw_1.Describe("evaluate(~"" + ls_expression + "~", " + string(row) + ")")
```

**Edit:** If you need to reuse dynamically a property into another expression in a DW, it becomes a bit tricky

- as you cannot evaluate a property directly with `eval()` because the property is in the form `"constant <tabulation> expression"` (including double quotes),
- you need then to either get the value directly
- or you need to evaluate the right part of the expression with taking care of the quotes (here I add one at the beginning, but corresponding ending quote was already given by the describe).

A multi-line **dw expression** would be:

```
if(pos(describe("some_field.protect"),"~t")<1,  /*if the prop has no tab*/
    describe("some_field.protect"),             /*no expression, get it directly*/
    describe(                               /*else eval the right part*/
        "evaluate(~""
            +mid(describe("some_field.protect"), pos(describe("some_field.protect"),"~t")+1)
            +",1)"          /* 1=for row 1 */
    )
)
```

Some notes:

- as you can see I call several times the describe of the expression, so it would be clearer to construct several computed fields to get in advance

  - the `describe()` and have only one expression to query
  - the value of the `pos()` of tabulation character
  - i have hardcoded the row 1 in my example (at the end of the `evaluate()`, you will need to use `string(getrow())` or some other function to evaluate the property at the correct row (or row 0 for header IIRC)
  - beware that if you do not put that expression directly in the dw painter but set it via PBScript, you would have to expand the double quotes `"` or simples simple quotes `'` with tilda characters depending on the kind of string used in the code

Comment: thanks .. is it possible to give something similar in the Expression window ? I tried different  combinations .. and everything leads to   invalid value i.e     >>! <<

Comment: you mean you want to directly get the evaluated expression in another field ?

Comment: Yes that is correct , and i want to do it through the expression window  and  not through the script .. Just like  the t2.text is set to expression  describe("t1.Text")  .. i want to have similar expression in the   t2 expression for the Text field.

Comment: @HelloWorld: I have expanded my answer to show you some dw black magic ;o)

Comment: Thanks @ Seki  .. I tried it ..and its getting me what I wanted.. I still need to understand it though :). Thanks for explaining the stuff.

Comment: @HelloWorld: you're welcome :o) Feel free to ask if you need more explanation on that code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe even a simpler solution:
Make t3 a computed field with the expression `describe("t2.text")`